# Media Query Navbar?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I am currently setting up a new app.  I was going to take the morning/afternoon to make it fully responsive with media queries(first time doing this in a real app).

I have http://bootswatch.com/yeti/ theme. Media Queries seem to be working correctly. I also have the gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.2.0'

The only thing not functioning correctly is my navbar.  Does anyone have experience with Bootstrap navbars 3.0? Here is some of the documentation I read

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

I am trying to get the effect where I get the small box in the upper right hand side of the navbar with three horizontal lines, and when you click, the links/options in the navbar drop down.

I thought the "collapse navbar-collapse" would create this effect but currently it isn't doing anything.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="page-header">
      <h1 id='type'>QueAndAnswer</h1>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <div>Logged in as<%= current_user.email %></div>
          <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<!--     <div class='container'>
 -->
      <div class='navbar-head'>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:3000">Que n A</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="htpp://localhost:3000/help">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>

          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Login with Github', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:github) %></li>
          <% end %>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this code up. Here is the final result:

```
<header>
  <div class="page-header">
      <h1 id='type'>QueAndAnswer</h1>
        <div id ='questionstats' class='jumbotron'></div>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <div>Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong></div>
          <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class='container'>
          <%= link_to 'Que n A', root_path, :class => 'navbar-brand' %>
            <button class ='navbar-toggle' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '.navHeaderCollapse'>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                <% else %>
                  <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to 'Login with Github', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:github) %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

Furthermore, I had to add the boostrap.js source to my assets/javascript folder in my rails app and add bootstrap to the asset pipeline in my application.js folder:

```
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts,       vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
```

Hopefully this helps anyone using bootstrap navs in the future, thanks!